# False Red eye detection in reddish atmosphere

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing

I am working on auto red eye removal. It works fine for normal image.
but i got problem when

- Image taken in reddish atmosphere.
  In above case it will detect red-eye in face due to reddishness in atmosphere as image doesn't contain red-eye face.

I have done following process to find red-eye

1. Detect eyeMat in face using haarcascade.
2. Find red-eye area using some redness thresold in eyeMat.
3. and fix that red-eye region.

Before

http://tinypic.com/r/29dk7yh/8

After

http://i61.tinypic.com/2vn12mv.jpg

**Questions**

To remove above false detection I am trying to find any color balancing that can reduce extra redness in image.
Can any OpenCV/matlab functions would help to reducing redness in image using some color balancing kind of stuff?

Comment: Why C++ tag? I don't see anything in your question related to C++

Comment: @Nishant : removed  c++ tag .

Comment: Post at least one "red" image and expected result

Comment: Still can't really clear what you are trying to do. Your question is somewhat broad in my opinion. Please post an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  This will help you getting a useful answer.

Comment: I guess you are looking for some kind of colour filter for images? Matlab could just read the RGB values of the picture and filter it. There are many methods to do this, I am not sure which specific technique you are looking for taking in to consideration of complexity,efficiency and accuracy.